# Problem with. Post. Comment Schemas - Mongoose/Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I'm creating a social media app, something like instagram. Being honest it is my first time working with a non-relational database so I am having some problems with my logic. I cannot understand how do you save the ids that create a relationship between schemas.  I had no trouble with user - post. But I'm having some errors with Post - Comment
I leave parts of my code so that you can understand my problem.
This is my Post Schema

```
    const postSchema = new Schema({
        created: {
            type: Date
        },
        descripcion:{
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Cada prenda debe ser descrita']
        },
        img: [{
            type: String
        }],
        user: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Usuario',
            required: [true, 'Debe existir una referencia a un usuario']
        }, 
        comment: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Comentario'
         }]
    });
    interface IPost extends Document{
        created: Date;
        descripcion: string;
        img: string[];
        cords: string;
        user: string;
        comment: string;
}
```

This is my Comment Schema:

```
const comentarioSchema = new Schema({
    created: {
        type: Date
    },
    autor: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Usuario',
        required: [true, 'Debe existir una referencia a un usuario']
    },
    contenido: {
        type:  String,
        required: [true, 'No se aceptan comentarios vacios']
    },
    post:{
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Post',
      required: [true, 'Debe existir una referencia al post al que este comentario pertenece']
    }
});
interface IComentario extends Document{
    created: Date;
    autor: string;
    contenido: string;
    post: string;
}
```

Finally, here is the the problem. I have a file called Comment.ts (Comentario.ts - In my mother tongue):

```
import { Router, Response } from "express";
import { verificaToken } from '../middlewares/autenticacion';
import { Comentario } from '../models/comentario.model';
const comentarioRoutes = Router();

comentarioRoutes.post('/',[verificaToken], (req:any, res: Response)=> {

    const body = req.body;
    body.autor = req.usuario._id;
    body.post = req.post._id;

    Comentario.create(body).then( async comentarioDB => {

        await comentarioDB.populate('usuario','-password').populate('post').execPopulate();

        res.json({
            ok:true,
            comentario: comentarioDB
        });
    }).catch(err=> {
        res.json(err)
    });



});

export default comentarioRoutes;
```

How can I store the post's id automatically, I tried with populate, using the request but I get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
    at /Users/mari/Desktop/Projects/ionic/fotos-server/dist/routes/comentario.js:21:26
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/mari/Desktop/Projects/ionic/fotos-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/mari/Desktop/Projects/ionic/fotos-server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at /Users/mari/Desktop/Projects/ionic/fotos-server/dist/middlewares/autenticacion.js:12:9
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Could you please point me where is my mistake or help me find a better approach.
I'd be very very grateful if you could help me!

Answer (score 0):

I created a minimal repo on Github to demonstrate a working example of using populate in the way you require.

There's a number of things I've outlined in the README.md specifically for you, explaining possible improvements and what the issue was.

I feel obligated to say, I'm a hobbyist developer so take my opinion/work lightly (likely different to professional engineers), although it should be enough to get you started!

As a bonus, I included an example of Controller->Service->Model design pattern as it focuses on decoupling presentation, business logic and data access.

I tried to avoid implementing any classes to keep things simple, although I'd personally recommend at least looking into the OOP paradigm.

https://github.com/Isolated-/mari-working-mongoose - feel free to let me know if I can of any further assistance and good luck!

For anyone stumbling across this answer with a similar issue, working code would look something like:

```js
export const commentController = {
  post: async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const body = req.body;
    const { postId, authorId, commentText } = body;

    // implement real validation logic
    if (!postId || !authorId || !commentText) {
      return res.status(400).json({
        error: 'Bad Request',
      });
    }

    const comment = await new Comment({
      post: postId,
      author: authorId,
      content: commentText,
    }).save();

    return res.status(201).json({
      ok: true,
      comment: await comment.populate('author').populate('post').execPopulate(),
    });
  },
};
```